# Why a text editor shows different from cat command

Tags: cat, man, editors

I run:

```
$ man cd > mancd
$ cat mancd
```

This shows as expected.
But when I open the file with VSCode and vim, they are completely different.

[image]

[image]

Why is it and how can I redirect the man page to a file correctly.

Comment: The output of `man` contains formatting trickery, like making characters bold by printing them, backspacing, and printing them again (this used to work directly on old printing terminals). When you view the output in an editor, you see the raw sequences instead of their intended effect (like you see when using `man` normally). As for storing just the plain text, `col -bx` is the usual filter (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/how-to-dump-a-man-page/296935#296935)).

Comment: @GordonDavisson This comment would make a pretty good answer

Answer (score 6):

Notice a lot of `^H` in the screenshot above. It means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> which produces the ASCII 08 character A.K.A. *Backspace*. When printing a character, move the cursor back with *Backspace* then [overwrite the same character again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overstrike)  then it appears **darker**. That's how **bold text** is achieved in a mechanical typewriter. Various modern electronic terminals also support that and many CLI tools do use it for text formatting. [ANSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) beginning with *Escape* (ASCII 27) are also commonly used for changing cursor position and text formatting properties like blinking, color, italic... Those `08` or `27` characters are called [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

**`cat` doesn't know anything about those bytes**. It just passes the ***raw byte stream*** to the terminal or to the next item in the pipe. Since the terminal knows about those control characters, it'll show the text properly. However `vi` or VS code isn't a terminal and translates the control characters before showing them inside their windows so that the accidental control characters don't mess up their screen and the terminal

To disable the control characters and just output the plain text then check the options of the tools you use. For `man` notice the [`Controlling formatted output`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) section in the man page. Try something like `man --ascii cd`

However most programs will automatically determine type of the output to know whether it should output the control characters or not, for example most GNU tools use the `--color` option like `ls` or `grep`. So does `man`:

> - MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING
>
>   Normally, when output is not being directed to a terminal (such as to a file or a pipe), formatting characters are discarded to make it easier to read the result without special tools. However, if `$MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` is set to any non-empty value, these formatting characters are retained. This may be useful for wrappers around man that can interpret formatting characters.

So it looks like your `man` is different or some formatting option has been specified by the alias or environment variables so it outputs the formatting even when you redirect the output to text file

See

- [What is the name of the formatting output from man?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118707/44425)
- [How to do: underline, bold, italic, strikethrough, color, background, and size in Gnome Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/528928/253474)

Comment: You will notice that `man cd --ascii` is not doing what you think it does.  However, `man --ascii cd` might do that (depending on whether you have a `cd` manual or not).  The more portable way of generating plain ASCII output `man`, would be using `-Tascii`, and then passing it through `col -b`.